# Select on multiple different values of the same field in a many to many relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not the sure the title is really helpful, so here is my problem, here are three tables :

cats :

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

tags :

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

cats_tags:

```
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_cat | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| id_tag | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

let's imagine that the tables are populated by 10 cats, and 5 tags (id 1 to 5) and that those cats are tagged with some random tags each.

how can I select all cats that have an entire list of tags ?

for example how can I list cats with tags 2 and 3 (it could be 1,2 and 3, or 2,3 and 4) but not cats who only have 2 or 3 or none of those two tags ?

I'm not sure it's standard sql, I'd want to do that with mysql.

**EDIT:**

I tried that :

```
select
    c.id, c.name
from
    cats c
inner join cats_tags r on c.id = r.id_cat
where
    r.id_tag in (:tags)
group by c.id
```

unitl I remembered that *in* would take any cat that has at least of the :tags list I asked for. and I only want cats that has all the tags I gave.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have already attempted so that we don't post retread solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might approach the problem like this:

```
SELECT cat_id
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT cat_id, tag_id
    FROM cat_tags
    WHERE tag_id IN (2,3)
  ) tag23
GROUP BY cat_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

The inline view is required because nothing you have shown prevents the same (cat, tag) pairing from appearing multiple times in `cat_tags`; the query could be expressed more simply if it could be assumed (because of a DB constraint) that such duplication would not occur.

You can join `cat` to the result if you need to get cat names.

Comment: there is no db constraint preventing the same (cat, tag) pairing, however, my app can't (theoretically) make that happen. What in your opinion, is the best solution ? Farhęg's or yours ?

Comment: Farhęg's relies on correlated subqueries, which are to be avoided where possible.  It doesn't make much difference for a DB the size that you describe, but you should cultivate the habit of avoiding them.

Comment: @JohnBollinger your solution has problem for if `tag_id=1,2,3`

Comment: @moo, if it were me writing this, by the way, I would drop `cat_tags.id` and give the table `(cat_id, tag_id)` as a composite primary key instead.

Comment: @Farhęg, my solution answers the question as originally posed.  For different numbers of tags to be queried, the tag list and the number of tags in it must both be parameters.

Comment: it will return `cats with only tagid 2 , 3 ` an will not return if `cat has tag ids: 1,2,3`

Comment: @Farhęg, you are mistaken.  The inline view filters out rows with tagids other than 2 or 3, so those are not reflected in the `COUNT(*)` performed by the outer query.

Comment: I didn't even know that was possible, I can still change how things work, I'm really not too far in it. how would that help me ? (to john, about "composite primary key")

Comment: @JohnBollinger I understand the logic very well, however this is good only for when the values are unique and will not work for none unique vals, anyway. good luck.

Comment: @Farhęg, sorry, you're still mistaken.  The inline view handles duplication via `SELECT DISTINCT`.  It works as advertised, as demonstrated in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd6a2/1/0.

Comment: @moo, ask first what `cat_tags.id` is doing for you.  Answer: nothing.  Dropping it saves a bit of space, and costs you nothing in representational power.  Having done that. making `(cat_id, tag_id)` a composite PK is approximately equivalent to creating a unique index on those columns -- it will prevent duplicate pairings being entered, and it will speed lookups by `cat_id` and by `(cat_id, tag_id)`.  And it would allow you to write a query such as I presented more simply.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, great, I didn't pay enough attention, I have no more comment, if I was the OP I accepted this answer +1.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I changed my relationship table to have a composite key as you advised. I then used a mix of your request and the one I posted. And it works like a charm. Of course I wanted to be able to do that query for any number of tags, but once I got the idea, it was a no brainer to adapt it for an arbitrary number of tags. I also understand the benefits from not using a solution doing as many selects as there are tags. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

use `where exists...subquery`:

```
select distinct c.* 
from cat c 
where exists
(  select 1 from cats_tags ct
   join tags t on ct.id_tag=t.id
   where t.id=2 and c.id=ct.id_cat
)
and exists
(  select 1 from cats_tags ct
   join tags t on ct.id_tag=t.id
   where t.id=3 and c.id=ct.id_cat
)
```